# Attribute selection from dataset

Tags: data-mining, dataset, weka

I work on a dataset with numeric values.The class labels has also numeric values.I made the 6 numeric class labels into one witch contain values like e.g happy_pleased. I want to insert the new .arff file into weka but i have a problem with the class @attribute as i declare it as nominal. Witch is the right type to declare the class label? I tried nominal but nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

You need to list the set of nominal values for the class in the `arff` file, comma-separated and enclosed in curly brackets `{}`. Here's an example:

```
@RELATION iris

@ATTRIBUTE sepallength  REAL
@ATTRIBUTE sepalwidth   REAL
@ATTRIBUTE petallength  REAL
@ATTRIBUTE petalwidth   REAL
@ATTRIBUTE class    {Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica}
```

In your case, `Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica` would be replaced with `happy_pleased,...`

If this still doesn't work, you can tell WEKA which attribute is the class in the explorer by choosing the correct attribute in the drop-down list above the histogram in the bottom right corner.